# JNI return random int

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a dll for a native java method that returns a random int i have made ones that work before but i cant get this one too m still new to programming with jni and i could use some help this is my c++ source code:

```
#include "IGNORE.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <iostream>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__I
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint i){
    srand(time(0));
    return (jint) (rand()%i)
  }

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__II
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint seed, jint i){
    srand((int)seed);
    return (jint) (rand()%i);
}
```

The error is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:##########: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Thanks :)

Source for JAVA:

```
public class NativeRandom {
    public static native int next(int h);
    public static native int next(int h, int seed);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("C:\\dlls\\RP.dll");
        System.out.println(next(4));
    }
}
```

Header file is:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class NativeRandom */

#ifndef _Included_NativeRandom
#define _Included_NativeRandom
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     NativeRandom
 * Method:    next
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__I
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

/*
 * Class:     NativeRandom
 * Method:    next
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__II
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: *but i cant get this one too* - What doesn't work? Why? What was the expected output? What did you get instead? How are you calling the native method? Is there any error? If yes, what is the stack trace?

Comment: You've posted requirements and some C++ but you still need to tell more -- How is this code not working? What's wrong with it? Where *exactly* are you stuck? Please go through and *study* the [help] and the [ask] to see what is expected of questions posted to this site.

Comment: I added the error and here is the source of the java

Comment: public class NativeRandom {
 public static native int next(int h);
 public static native int next(int h, int seed);
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.load("C:\\dlls\\RP.dll");
  System.out.println(next(4));
 }
}

Comment: ok i added the source java code

Comment: [Some possible duplicates/similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F+java+jni+UnsatisfiedLinkError+c%2B%2B)

Comment: At the Moment, you have two methods with the same name but you use only one. Try reducing the example to get a minimal not working code by removing (commenting out) one method.

Comment: I assume that you have a combination of jdk, C++ compile settings and Eclipse that matches regarding CPU architecture (32bit/64 bit)

Comment: I am using Dev-C++ for the c++ file and everything is configured for a 64bit cpu @milbrandt

Comment: and the 64bit JDK? There are editions of jdk1.8.0_151 for x64 and x86

Comment: yes the jdk is 64bit i always make sure to get that one

Comment: @milbrandt thanks for the help i eventually did alot more research and tests and got it working but thanks for the help im pretty sure it was the imports which messed it up but not 100% sure but thanks anyway

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution!!!! I fixed it by doing some research and through trial and error i figured out that my imports were messing up the DLL

Cpp file:

```
/* Replace "dll.h" with the name of your header */
#include "IGNORE.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__I
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint i){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = (rand()%i)+1;
    return n;
  }

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__II
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint seed, jint i){
    srand(seed);
    int n =(rand()%i)+1;
    return n;
}
```

Header file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class NativeRandom */

    #ifndef _Included_NativeRandom
    #define _Included_NativeRandom
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    /*
     * Class:     NativeRandom
     * Method:    next
     * Signature: (I)I
     */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__I
      (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

    /*
     * Class:     NativeRandom
     * Method:    next
     * Signature: (II)I
     */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_next__II
      (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif
```

Comment: Don't use the answer section to add more information to your post.

Comment: @EJoshuaS it is the solution i just forgot to add why i was in a bit of a hurry

Answer (score 0):

You CPP file doesn't include the .h file and it doesn't have `extern "C"` declarations of its own. So, the methods are compiled with C++ signatures, so they cannot be found by the JVM, which expects `extern "C"` signatures as per the .h file.

The easy fix is to include the .h file.

Comment: It does and it was the imports that messed it up but i fixed it now

Comment: i named the files IGNORE.cpp and IGNORE.h because i didnt feel like naming them